# drawing an economic graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the following curve

[image]

I have this code, but I could not edit it; any help!

[image]

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=0:6*pi,
samples=100,
axis lines*=left,
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
width=13cm, height=8cm
]
\addplot [thick, gray] {x};
\addplot [thick, black] {x + 4*sin(deg(x)) * sin(deg(x/6))^0.5}
node [pos=0.1, anchor=south] {Peak}
node [pos=0.3, anchor=south, sloped] {Expansion}
node [pos=0.49, anchor=south, sloped] {Recession}
;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: When you write "I could not edit it" - I do not suppose that you actually mean that you can not edit it? Are your file locked? Do you not have an editor? Make your code compilable and describe what your problem is.

Comment: So you take some random code completely without making any obvious alterations, and expected someone else to do the work?

Comment: I have a limited tikz experience, so I tried to edit an existing code but I do not know how.

Comment: What you are using here is called `PGFplots` - You need to read relevant parts of the manual and make your code compilable. Also try to do something logically like replacing "Peak" with what you want, remove `sloped` etc. This site is not meant for others to do your work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example of a graph with variations:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:6*pi,
                  samples=100,
                  axis lines=center,
                  xtick={0},
                  ytick=\empty,
                  xlabel={$x$},
                  ylabel={$f(x)$},
                  xmin=-0.5,
                  xmax=20,
                  width=13cm,
                  height=8cm]
% Plot of the main function
\addplot [thick, black] {6*sin(deg(x)) * sin(deg(x/6))^0.5};
% Nodes on the x axis
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (a0) at (pi, 0) {};
\node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.75] (a1) at (2.5, -1) {$P_{1}$};
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (b0) at (2*pi, 0) {};
\node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.75] (b1) at (7, -1) {$P_{2}$};
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (c0) at (3*pi, 0) {};
\node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.75] (c1) at (11, -1) {$P_{3}$};
% Nodes on the main function and the axis
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (a2) at (pi/2, 3) {};
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (a3) at (pi/2, 0) {};
\node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.75] (a4) at (pi/2, -1) {$P_{0}$};
% Lines to join the nodes on the function to the axis
\draw[dashed] (a2) -- (a3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I haven't precisely placed the maximum, but this can be adjusted if you change the position of the nodes.

[image]

You can also add some commands to draw the horizontal arrows as per the drawing above.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:6*pi,
                  samples=100,
                  axis lines=center,
                  xtick={0},
                  ytick=\empty,
                  xlabel={$x$},
                  ylabel={$f(x)$},
                  xmin=-0.5,
                  xmax=20,
                  width=13cm,
                  height=8cm]
% Plot of the main function
\addplot [thick, black] {6*sin(deg(x)) * sin(deg(x/6))^0.5};
% Nodes on the x axis
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (a0) at (pi, 0) {};
\node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.75] (a1) at (2.5, -1) {$\overline{P_{1}}$};
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (b0) at (2*pi, 0) {};
\node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.75] (b1) at (7, -1) {$\overline{P_{2}}$};
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (c0) at (3*pi, 0) {};
\node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.75] (c1) at (11, -1) {$\overline{P_{3}}$};
% Nodes on the main function and the axis
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (a2) at (pi/2, 3) {};
\node[fill=black, circle, draw=black, scale=0.4] (a3) at (pi/2, 0) {};
\node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.75] (a4) at (pi/2, -1) {$\overline{P_{0}}$};
% Lines to join the nodes on the function to the axis
\draw[dashed] (a2) -- (a3);
% Arrow commands
\draw[->] (pi/2, 1) -- (1.5*pi/2,1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope that makes it clearer.

Romain

Answer (score 2):

This site is full of such examples. Here is one more.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{dot/.style={blue,circle,fill,scale=0.4}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=1.2,label distance=-2pt]
    \draw [->,name path=x axis] (0,0) -- (9,0) node [right] {$P$};
    \draw [->] (0,-2) -- (0,0) node [left] {$0$} -- (0,3) node[left]{Ex.P.};
      \draw [red,smooth, domain=0:2.5*pi, name path=wave,thick,
      samples=100] plot
      ({\x+0.4},{cos(2*\x r)});
    \fill[blue]  [name intersections={of={wave} and {x axis}, name=x, total=\n}]
    \foreach \X in {1,...,\n} {(x-\X) node[dot,label={-90+cos(\X*180)*45)}:{$\bar
    P_\X$}] {} };
    \foreach \Y/\Z [count=\X] in
    {0.6/{$P_1'$},2/{$P_1''$},2.6/{$P_2'$},3.4/{$P_2''$}}
    {\path[name path=tmp] (\Y,-2) -- (\Y,3);
     \draw[name intersections={of={wave} and {tmp}, by=y-\X}]
     let \p1 = (y-\X) in (y-\X)
     --(\Y,0) node[blue,yshift={-1*sign(\y1)*2.5mm}] {\Z};
     \ifnum\X=1
     \draw[->] ($(\Y,0)!0.5!(y-\X)$) -- ++ (0.2,0);
     \else
     \ifnum\X=4
     \draw[->] ($(\Y,0)!0.5!(y-\X)$) -- ++ (0.2,0);
     \else
     \draw[->] ($(\Y,0)!0.5!(y-\X)$) -- ++ (-0.2,0);
     \fi
     \fi
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]